# my CSV file have some email addresses. Some of them have incomplete address. How do I make them fully recognizable using python?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, data-science

I'm a begineer in data science with python.
I'm working on a Dataset in which i've to do following tasks:
 Using the Python petl:

**a.** clean the data in the `clinics.csv`. This involves using python and Regex to
standardise email addresses so they are usable as a html link, and

**b.** output the merged and cleaned data into a CSV file with the name
`clinic_locations.csv`.

So, far i'm able to do handle a part of point (**b**) i.e. i've easily extracted data from the xml file and combined it with the csv file.
But the problem with this is

**I can't clean the data of my CSV file**

This is my CSV file :

```
ID  Name    Suburb  State   Postcode    Email
1   Hurstville Clinic   Hurstville  NSW 1493    hurstville
2   Sydney Centre Clinic    Sydney  NSW 2000    sydney@myclinic.com.au
3   Auburn Clinic   Auburn  NSW 2144    auburn@myclinic.com.au
4   Riverwood Clinic    Riverwood   NSW 2210    riverwood@myclinic.com.au
```

as you can see the data in email column is incomplete and whole links are unusable.
Can anyone help me from starting.

updated:
the output that I'm getting is

```
   ID                     Name       Suburb State  Postcode  \
0   1        Hurstville Clinic   Hurstville   NSW      1493
1   2     Sydney Centre Clinic       Sydney   NSW      2000
2   3            Auburn Clinic       Auburn   NSW      2144
3   4         Riverwood Clinic    Riverwood   NSW      2210
4   5        Fingal Bay Clinic   Fingal Bay   NSW      2315
5   6        Harrington Clinic   Harrington   NSW      2427
6   7       Back Forest Clinic  Back Forest   NSW      2535
7   8         Jindabyne Clinic    Jindabyne   NSW      2627
8   9          Benolong Clinic     Benolong   NSW      2830
9  10  Melbourne Centre Clinic    Melbourne   VIC      3000

                         Email
0   hurstville@myclinic.com.au
1       sydney@myclinic.com.au
2       auburn@myclinic.com.au
3    riverwood@myclinic.com.au
4   fingal bay@myclinic.com.au
5   harrington@myclinic.com.au
6  back forest@myclinic.com.au
7   jindabyne @myclinic.com.au
8     benolong@myclinic.com.au
9    melbourne@myclinic.com.au
```

Comment: you want to remove or add @myclinic in email id?

Comment: add @myclinic to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will help assuming you have similar domain for all email ids:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv("clinic_locations.csv")  #Provide complete path to your file

df['Email']=df['Email'].apply(lambda x: x if '@' in str(x) else str(x)+'@myclinic.com.au')

#To see data frame
print(df.head(10))
```

Comment: This did not helped me!

Comment: KeyError: 'Email'
i think I'm not doing it right way.

Comment: looks like your column name is different.

Comment: what's the output of `df.columns`  ?

Comment: Sir, I wasn't able to make a correct code to use it. I need something from scratch.

Comment: Thanks For Help.
the output it is showing has email in next line. Can you tell me why?

Comment: I hope this is what you wanted. You are getting email column in next line because it is not able to fit in whatever editor you are using. You can google it to change the setting. If it helped accept the answer and upvote it.

Comment: I just stored the output in a csv file i'm getting a new column in starting. Any Idea?

Comment: You might be getting an index. Use `df.to_csv("file.csv", index= False)`