# python and Regex to standardise email addresses so they are usable as a html link

Tags: python, regex, csv

I'd never USED REGEX before so I've no idea.
Can anyone Help me from Scratch?
I've a CSV file in this there is a column consisting email address.
I've to use Python and Regex to standardise email addresses so they are usable as a HTML link.

```
ID  Name    Suburb  State   Postcode    Email
1   Hurstville Clinic   Hurstville  NSW 1493    hurstville@myclinic.com.au
2   Sydney Centre Clinic    Sydney  NSW 2000    sydney@myclinic.com.au
3   Auburn Clinic   Auburn  NSW 2144    auburn@myclinic.com.au
4   Riverwood Clinic    Riverwood   NSW 2210    riverwood@myclinic.com.au
5   Fingal Bay Clinic   Fingal Bay  NSW 2315    fingal bay@myclinic.com.au
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "standardise email adress"?

Comment: what do you want?

Comment: I want to use these email address as a usable HTML links.
i've to develop a RESTful web service later in which i need those Email address to point to their respective Geolocation.

Comment: if they are to be links, then you want to extract everything after the '@'?

Comment: @FlyingTeller can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: I am still not sure what your goal is. Could you make an example? Let's say you have `mail="hurstville@myclinic.com.au"`. What do you want to achieve? What is your desired output?

Comment: ***clean the data in the 'clinics.csv'. This involves using python and Regex to
standardise email addresses so they are usable as a html link***
this is my task.

Comment: Writing the same thing in bold and italics does not make it clearer. Why is that email not "standardised"? To what should it be changed?

Comment: @GauravKaushal If you don't understand your assigment because it is unclear then I think the best step would be to ask your teacher/instructor. We will not be able to help you with only these limited informations

Comment: looks like this is the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48700691/my-csv-file-have-some-email-addresses-some-of-them-have-incomplete-address-how

Comment: i've to make these email hyperlinks. @FlyingTeller

Comment: Well, you didn't ask how to make mail adresses into hyperlinks, you asked how to standardise them, which is a different question

Comment: @FlyingTeller
i know how to do it manually but using regex i don't know.

Comment: I'm fairly sure OP wants to extract all fields from this csv, then display the emails as links in an HTML file, then show the geo data when an email is clicked. Looks like that's the *assignment*.

Comment: @nitely you're right. That's the assignment.

Comment: true, but there is no regex needed here. The csv can be read using e.g. Pandas and then the Email column can be iterated to process every mail adress.

Comment: they are asking for a regex solution regardless.

Comment: @FlyingTeller but i've to use REGEX

Comment: @GauravKaushal The regex solution to extract the mail adresses is already given. You only have to add the processing of every mail adress which you said you know how to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Regex**: [`\S+@\S+`](https://regex101.com/r/7ZEGgE/1)

Details:

- `\S` Matches any non-whitespace character
- `+` Matches between one and unlimited times

**Python code**:

```
text = """ID  Name    Suburb  State   Postcode    Email
1   Hurstville Clinic   Hurstville  NSW 1493    hurstville@myclinic.com.au
2   Sydney Centre Clinic    Sydney  NSW 2000    sydney@myclinic.com.au
3   Auburn Clinic   Auburn  NSW 2144    auburn@myclinic.com.au
4   Riverwood Clinic    Riverwood   NSW 2210    riverwood@myclinic.com.au
5   Fingal Bay Clinic   Fingal Bay  NSW 2315    fingal bay@myclinic.com.au"""

emails = re.findall(r'\S+@\S+', text)

for x in range(0, len(emails)):
    emails[x] = '<a href="%s"></a>' % emails[x];

print(emails)
```

Output:

```
['<a href="hurstville@myclinic.com.au"></a>', '<a href="sydney@myclinic.com.au"></a>', '<a href="auburn@myclinic.com.au"></a>', '<a href="riverwood@myclinic.com.au"></a>', '<a href="bay@myclinic.com.au"></a>']
```

[Code demo](http://rextester.com/FRUS76763)

Comment: I really appreciate the answer. but the output should be the hyperlinks of those emails.

Comment: @Gaurav Kaushal Updated! What about now?

Comment: Thank you. This is highly Appreciated.